# Remove common characters or duplicates in a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove duplicates in a string upon user input. Here''s my code:

```
userinput = input("Enter a word:")
def duplicates_removal(x):
      for i in range(len(x)-1):
             if x[i] == x[i +1]:
                     return duplicates_removal(x.replace(x[i], ' '))
      return x 

print(duplicates_removal(userInput))
```

When I run the code, and input the string Bananas,  it produces the output Bananas with the duplicates not removed. Is there any flaws in the code? Also I prefer not using built in functions for this since I just started learning on string manipulation.

```
Input: Bananas
Output desired: Bans
```

Comment: you're just comparing each character to the previous character (`x[i] == x[i+1]`) that's the flaw.

Comment: You say "I prefer not using built in functions for this", but you're using the built-in `range` and `len` functions, and the `str.replace` method, not to mention `input` and `print`.

Comment: There are several better ways to do this. It's _possible_ to make your recursive approach work with a couple of minor alterations (and no additional functions), but the resulting code is inefficient and not particularly easy to read. I guess it makes a fun "code golf" puzzle, but doing this sort of thing is _not_ a great way for a beginner to learn Python.

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/ByCa4R07

Answer (score -1):

```
def duplicates_removal(x):
    l = []
    for each in x:
        if each not in l:
            l.append(each)
    return "".join(l)
```

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The OP isn't asking for the best algorithm for this task. They want to understand why their existing code doesn't do what they expect. And they certainly _didn't_ ask for someone to write the code for them.